# Gnuplot Charts Wild Fluctuations

Tags: gnuplot

I have a simple chart plotting off CSV data. Recently, there have been some wild fluctuations in the chart that I can't explain.

The chart:

[image: Plot of three temperature values.]

The data:

```
"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SS","Pressure","Pressure Normal","Basement Temp","Downstairs Temp","Energy C1","Energy C2","Garage Temp","Lux","Lux Low","Indoor Hum","Main Attic Hum","Main Attic Temp","Outdoor Hum","Outdoor Temp","Outdoor Freeze","Rain Today","Septic Pump","Target Hum","Target Hum Low","Target Hum High","Upstairs Temp","Septic Low","Septic High","Wind Direction","Wind Speed"
2015-10-29 22:00:01.017000,29.95,30,68.0,69.0,639.986,381.38,45.0,0.0,30,49.0,39.0,49.0,94.0,46.0,32,0.0,176.884,45,15,45,66.0,165,185,139,2.0
2015-10-29 22:15:00.858000,29.96,30,68.0,69.0,526.95,283.151,45.0,0.0,30,49.0,39.0,48.9,92.0,46.0,32,0.0,178.132,45,15,45,67.0,165,185,146,2.0
2015-10-29 22:30:00.767000,29.96,30,68.0,68.0,462.525,362.072,45.0,0.0,30,49.0,39.0,48.8,92.0,46.0,32,0.0,178.654,45,15,45,66.0,165,185,138,5.0
2015-10-29 22:45:00.836000,29.97,30,68.0,68.0,473.075,274.232,45.0,0.0,30,49.0,39.0,48.4,91.0,46.0,32,0.0,179.509,45,15,45,66.0,165,185,147,2.0
2015-10-29 23:00:01.729000,29.98,30,68.0,68.0,460.024,355.895,45.0,0.0,30,49.0,39.0,48.3,89.0,46.0,32,0.0,179.626,45,15,45,66.0,165,185,150,2.0
2015-10-29 23:15:01.481000,29.99,30,68.0,68.0,470.404,266.078,44.0,0.0,30,49.0,39.0,48.1,90.0,46.0,32,0.0,179.759,45,15,45,66.0,165,185,140,1.0
2015-10-29 23:30:00.948000,29.99,30,67.0,67.0,578.765,361.633,44.0,0.0,30,49.0,39.0,48.1,90.0,45.0,32,0.0,181.606,45,15,45,65.0,165,185,143,0.0
2015-10-29 23:45:00.978000,29.99,30,67.0,67.0,578.813,265.008,44.0,0.0,30,48.0,39.0,47.7,90.0,45.0,32,0.0,180.662,45,15,45,65.0,165,185,143,0.0
2015-10-30 00:00:01.018000,30.0,30,67.0,67.0,571.851,358.56,44.0,0.0,30,48.0,39.0,47.6,90.0,45.0,32,0.0,182.406,45,15,45,65.0,165,185,154,0.0
2015-10-30 00:15:00.703000,30.0,30,67.0,67.0,461.92,266.449,44.0,0.0,30,48.0,40.0,47.5,90.0,45.0,32,0.0,179.058,45,15,45,65.0,165,185,170,1.0
2015-10-30 00:30:00.676000,30.0,30,68.0,67.0,459.044,364.956,44.0,0.0,30,48.0,40.0,47.3,90.0,45.0,32,0.0,176.376,45,15,45,65.0,165,185,152,1.0
2015-10-30 00:45:01.742000,30.0,30,67.0,67.0,464.856,268.456,44.0,0.0,30,49.0,40.0,47.2,90.0,45.0,32,0.0,178.552,45,15,45,65.0,165,185,160,0.0
2015-10-30 01:00:01.412000,30.0,30,67.0,67.0,462.717,373.676,44.0,0.0,30,48.0,40.0,47.0,91.0,45.0,32,0.0,177.563,45,15,45,65.0,165,185,140,1.0
2015-10-30 01:15:01.398000,30.0,30,67.0,66.0,465.183,265.674,44.0,0.0,30,48.0,40.0,46.9,91.0,45.0,32,0.0,179.081,45,15,45,64.0,165,185,139,1.0
2015-10-30 01:30:01.690000,30.0,30,67.0,66.0,466.075,276.496,43.0,0.0,30,48.0,40.0,46.8,91.0,45.0,32,0.0,178.243,45,15,45,64.0,165,185,125,0.0
2015-10-30 01:45:01.222000,30.01,30,67.0,66.0,583.214,266.92,43.0,0.0,30,48.0,40.0,46.5,90.0,45.0,32,0.0,179.797,45,15,45,64.0,165,185,125,0.0
2015-10-30 02:00:01.147000,30.02,30,67.0,66.0,577.097,265.52,43.0,0.0,30,48.0,40.0,46.3,90.0,45.0,32,0.0,180.246,45,15,45,64.0,165,185,161,0.0
2015-10-30 02:15:01.130000,30.03,30,67.0,66.0,570.447,268.758,43.0,0.0,30,48.0,40.0,46.2,92.0,45.0,32,0.0,181.472,45,15,45,64.0,165,185,140,0.0
2015-10-30 02:30:01.124000,30.03,30,67.0,66.0,466.977,266.9,43.0,0.0,30,48.0,40.0,46.1,92.0,44.0,32,0.0,179.358,45,15,45,64.0,165,185,157,0.0
2015-10-30 02:45:00.935000,30.03,30,67.0,66.0,467.547,265.461,43.0,0.0,30,47.0,40.0,45.7,92.0,44.0,32,0.0,178.06,45,15,45,64.0,165,185,148,0.0
2015-10-30 03:00:00.730000,30.04,30,67.0,65.0,467.852,270.395,42.0,0.0,30,48.0,41.0,45.5,91.0,44.0,32,0.0,180.963,45,15,45,64.0,165,185,148,0.0
2015-10-30 03:15:00.669000,30.05,30,67.0,65.0,470.797,269.087,42.0,0.0,30,48.0,41.0,45.1,91.0,43.0,32,0.0,181.562,45,15,45,64.0,165,185,148,0.0
2015-10-30 03:30:00.597000,30.06,30,67.0,65.0,471.425,266.515,41.0,0.0,30,48.0,41.0,44.7,91.0,43.0,32,0.0,181.108,45,15,45,64.0,165,185,148,0.0
2015-10-30 03:45:01.544000,30.06,30,67.0,65.0,466.103,266.759,41.0,0.0,30,48.0,41.0,44.6,92.0,42.0,32,0.0,181.674,45,15,45,65.0,165,185,148,0.0
2015-10-30 04:00:01.428000,30.06,30,67.0,65.0,468.903,269.099,41.0,0.0,30,48.0,41.0,44.4,92.0,42.0,32,0.0,181.132,45,15,45,64.0,165,185,148,0.0
2015-10-30 04:15:01.112000,30.07,30,67.0,64.0,1133.93,265.94,40.0,0.0,30,48.0,41.0,44.0,92.0,42.0,32,0.0,178.97,45,15,45,63.0,165,185,148,0.0
2015-10-30 04:30:01.129000,30.08,30,67.0,65.0,575.551,269.082,40.0,0.0,30,48.0,41.0,43.8,94.0,41.0,32,0.0,179.605,45,15,45,64.0,165,185,143,0.0
2015-10-30 04:45:00.949000,30.08,30,67.0,64.0,2912.436,342.048,40.0,0.0,30,48.0,41.0,43.7,95.0,42.0,32,0.0,179.017,45,15,45,64.0,165,185,168,0.0
2015-10-30 05:00:00.969000,30.09,30,67.0,66.0,550.604,279.568,40.0,0.0,30,49.0,41.0,44.8,95.0,42.0,32,0.0,177.197,45,15,45,68.0,165,185,184,2.0
2015-10-30 05:15:00.709000,30.1,30,67.0,66.0,586.835,549.631,40.0,0.0,30,49.0,41.0,45.4,95.0,41.0,32,0.0,178.466,45,15,45,69.0,165,185,148,1.0
2015-10-30 05:30:00.901000,30.1,30,67.0,66.0,596.532,278.354,39.0,0.0,30,49.0,41.0,46.1,95.0,41.0,32,0.0,175.013,45,15,45,70.0,165,185,161,1.0
2015-10-30 05:45:01.672000,30.1,30,67.0,65.0,1506.813,1119.999,39.0,0.0,30,50.0,41.0,46.2,95.0,41.0,32,0.0,174.623,45,15,45,67.0,165,185,155,0.0
2015-10-30 06:00:01.509000,30.12,30,68.0,67.0,1516.573,266.874,39.0,0.0,30,49.0,41.0,46.6,95.0,41.0,32,0.0,175.143,45,15,45,69.0,165,185,155,0.0
2015-10-30 06:15:01.207000,30.12,30,68.0,68.0,1072.979,376.114,39.0,0.0,30,49.0,41.0,46.7,95.0,41.0,32,0.0,172.09,45,15,45,69.0,165,185,155,0.0
2015-10-30 06:30:01.312000,30.12,30,69.0,70.0,854.998,281.418,38.0,0.0,30,49.0,41.0,46.6,95.0,40.0,32,0.0,172.968,45,15,45,69.0,165,185,155,0.0
2015-10-30 06:45:01.234000,30.12,30,69.0,69.0,596.209,374.564,38.0,0.0,30,49.0,41.0,45.1,95.0,40.0,32,0.0,174.648,45,15,45,68.0,165,185,155,0.0
2015-10-30 07:00:00.883000,30.12,30,68.0,68.0,596.669,279.735,38.0,0.0,30,49.0,41.0,44.5,95.0,40.0,32,0.0,175.019,45,15,45,67.0,165,185,155,0.0
2015-10-30 07:15:01.066000,30.12,30,68.0,68.0,489.209,376.154,38.0,0.0,30,49.0,41.0,44.0,96.0,41.0,32,0.0,175.471,45,15,45,66.0,165,185,155,0.0
2015-10-30 07:30:01.019000,30.12,30,68.0,67.0,398.586,269.955,38.0,0.0,30,49.0,41.0,43.5,96.0,41.0,32,0.0,178.401,45,15,45,66.0,165,185,155,0.0
2015-10-30 07:45:00.784000,30.12,30,68.0,67.0,397.613,369.828,37.0,0.0,30,49.0,42.0,42.8,96.0,41.0,32,0.0,176.625,45,15,45,66.0,165,185,155,0.0
2015-10-30 08:00:00.919000,30.13,30,67.0,67.0,394.231,284.606,37.0,0.0,30,48.0,42.0,42.6,96.0,41.0,32,0.0,176.026,45,15,45,65.0,165,185,155,0.0
2015-10-30 08:15:00.672000,30.14,30,67.0,66.0,403.669,373.851,37.0,0.0,30,48.0,42.0,42.4,96.0,41.0,32,0.0,180.215,45,15,45,65.0,165,185,156,0.0
2015-10-30 08:30:00.527000,30.13,30,67.0,66.0,391.887,268.734,37.0,0.0,30,48.0,42.0,42.5,96.0,42.0,32,0.0,172.674,45,15,45,65.0,165,185,146,0.0
2015-10-30 08:45:01.630000,30.13,30,67.0,66.0,388.044,265.381,38.0,0.0,30,48.0,43.0,43.8,97.0,42.0,32,0.0,174.12,45,15,45,65.0,165,185,125,1.0
2015-10-30 09:00:01.461000,30.14,30,67.0,66.0,506.085,263.921,38.0,0.0,30,49.0,43.0,44.7,97.0,42.0,32,0.0,174.449,45,15,45,65.0,165,185,36,0.0
2015-10-30 09:15:01.443000,30.15,30,67.0,66.0,515.15,270.162,39.0,0.0,30,48.0,43.0,45.7,97.0,43.0,32,0.0,173.922,45,15,45,65.0,165,185,342,0.0
2015-10-30 09:30:01.428000,30.16,30,67.0,66.0,503.095,266.903,39.0,0.0,30,48.0,43.0,46.8,97.0,44.0,32,0.0,179.962,45,15,45,64.0,165,185,53,0.0
2015-10-30 09:45:01.175000,30.16,30,67.0,66.0,406.591,268.547,40.0,0.0,30,48.0,43.0,49.3,97.0,45.0,32,0.0,180.893,45,15,45,64.0,165,185,286,1.0
2015-10-30 10:00:01.024000,30.17,30,67.0,66.0,408.512,267.207,41.0,0.0,30,48.0,43.0,50.8,97.0,46.0,32,0.0,182.111,45,15,45,64.0,165,185,240,1.0
```

The script (run on Gnuplot 5.0 patch 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/env gnuplot
reset

#### Stats and Setup ####
set terminal pngcairo enhanced background "#000000" font "Arial,10" size 400,200 truecolor
datafile_temperatures_indoor = "/Users/username/Dropbox/Public/charts.csv"
set datafile separator ','

stats datafile_temperatures_indoor using 2 nooutput
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

set output "/Users/username/Dropbox/Public/TemperaturesIndoor.png"

now = time(0)
today_midnight = strptime('%Y-%m-%d', strftime('%Y-%m-%d', now))

#### Plot Parameters and Styles ####
set tics textcolor rgb "#666666"
set border linetype rgb "#666666"
set boxwidth 0.25 relative
set style fill solid 1.0
set style line 1 linetype rgb "#FFFFFF" linewidth 1 pointtype 6 # white
set style line 2 linetype rgb "#333333" linewidth 1 pointtype 6 # light gray
set style line 3 linetype rgb "#666666" linewidth 1 pointtype 6 # gray
set style line 4 linetype rgb "#999999" linewidth 1 pointtype 6 # dark gray
set style line 5 linetype rgb "#000000" linewidth 1 pointtype 6 # black
set style line 6 linetype rgb "#FF3333" linewidth 1 pointtype 6 # red
set style line 7 linetype rgb "#FF6600" linewidth 1 pointtype 6 # orange
set style line 8 linetype rgb "#FFFF00" linewidth 1 pointtype 6 # yellow
set style line 9 linetype rgb "#336600" linewidth 1 pointtype 6 # green
set style line 10 linetype rgb "#0000FF" linewidth 1 pointtype 6 # blue
set style line 11 linetype rgb "#000033" linewidth 1 pointtype 6 # indigo
set style line 12 linetype rgb "#6600FF" linewidth 1 pointtype 6 # violet

#### Key Parameters ####
set nokey

#### X Axis Parameters ####
unset mxtics
set xdata time 
set xrange [now - 72*60*60 : now]
set xtics 72*60*60, 24*60*60 format "%a" nomirror

#### Y Axis Parameters ####
set ytics format "%2.0f" nomirror

#### Plot the Data ####
plot datafile_temperatures_indoor using 1:4 every ::2 title column with lines smooth csplines linestyle 8,\
     datafile_temperatures_indoor using 1:5 every ::2 title column with lines smooth csplines linestyle 12,\
     datafile_temperatures_indoor using 1:22 every ::2 title column with lines smooth csplines linestyle 6
```

The stats:

```
* FILE: 
  Records:           319
  Out of range:        0
  Invalid:             0
  Blank:               0
  Data Blocks:         1

* COLUMN: 
  Mean:              66.3856
  Std Dev:            1.7577
  Sample StdDev:      1.7605
  Skewness:           0.5592
  Kurtosis:           2.5369
  Avg Dev:            0.9624
  Sum:            21177.0000
  Sum Sq.:       1.40683e+06

  Mean Err.:          0.0984
  Std Dev Err.:       0.0696
  Skewness Err.:      0.1371
  Kurtosis Err.:      0.2743

  Minimum:           63.0000 [ 25]
  Maximum:           71.0000 [267]
  Quartile:          65.0000 
  Median:            66.0000 
  Quartile:          67.0000
```

I don't see an out of range value in the data; sometimes the out of range obs is wildly negative (-60), sometimes wildly positive +240). I'm wondering if there's a bug in the implementation of csplines under 5.0.  Any advice would be most appreciated.

Cheers.

[EDIT] With mcsplines:

[image: Same date, mcsplines.]

With Bezier (which I think I prefer):

[image: Same data, Bezier.]

Comment: No very likely this isn't a bug. Such overshoots can happen with `csplines` smoothing and are normal. If you don't want that, try the `mcsplines` smoothing option. In any case, please give a data set which shows the described problem. The snippet you give doesn't even allow to run the script...

Comment: Hi Christoph - Stack is balking at the size of the datafile (too many lines.)  I will try mcsplines.  I'm sure that you're right (you always are!)  Cheers!

Comment: Ok, I should have said: "Please give a full but minimal data set which shows the error" ;) Usually such problems can be broken down to a data set with 5 to 10 lines. See also [smooth peaks in gnuplot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30594733/2604213) for a demonstration of the different spline smoothing options.

Comment: Keep in mind, that `bezier` computes a single bezier using all points. Not sure if this always gives the desired result.

Comment: Thanks Christoph.  I've added more observations.  Understand your point about `bezier` and will look at some other options.  Given the nature of the data points, there may be no perfect solution for me.  However, seeing the peaks and valleys (if they're true peaks and valleys) may suffice.